# What does "whack" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I was reading some comments on a video clip, and someone says that the `song is whack`. What does it mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a slang term, presumably derived from *wacky* (meaning a sort of crazy, different from normal, weird, unusual).

However, "wack" has a slightly different meaning; it means "lame" or "uncool" (ie, a modifier indicating low quality).  [Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=wack)  has a few examples.